# Proof that complex conjugate of polynomial result equals pynomial result with complex conjugated argument

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

This question feels uneasy to be expressed by words for me, however, I'm asked to prove this:

$$P(\overline{a+bi}) = \overline{P(a+bi)}$$

Of course, $\overline{a+bi} = a-bi$.

Comment: If you show what fkraiem said than you have $$\overline{P(a+bi)}=\overline{(a+bi)+(a+bi)x+...+(a+bi)x^n}$$

$$\iff\overline{P(a+bi)}=(\overline{a+bi})+(\overline{a+bi})x+...+(\overline{a+bi})x^n=P(\overline{a+bi})$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note:* This is true only if $P$ has *real* coefficients. For example if $P(z) = iz$, then $P(i) \ne \overline{P(-i)}$.

*Hint:* It is sufficient to prove that

- $\overline{a+bi} + \overline{c+di} = \overline{(a+bi)+(c+di)}$;
- $\overline{a+bi} \times \overline{c+di} = \overline{(a+bi)\times(c+di)}$; and
- If $x$ is real then $\overline{x} = x$.

Comment: Another nice way to complete the proof is to notice that if $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, then we can write $f(x) = c + xg(x)$ where $c$ is a constant and $g(x)$ has degree $n-1$. Then use induction on the degree of $P$.